# Image Sorting With a button function

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have two button function
sort for most like and most recent
This is just simulation, could be hardcoded

how do i link the button with the function.

This is the source code from one of the source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="function1">Sort Most Like</button>
<button onclick="function2">Sort Most Recent</button>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<script>



const imgArr = [
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Recent: "24/1/2018", Likes: 6 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Recent: "24/3/2018", Likes: 2 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Recent: "25/1/2018", Likes: 3 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Recent: "24/2/2018", Likes: 1 },
];

const html = imgArr.sort((a, b) => {
return a.Likes + b.Likes
}).map(imageItem => {
  return `<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src=${
    imageItem.src
  } style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
      <figcaption>Name: ${imageItem.Name}<br>
        <span>Likes: ${imageItem.Likes}</span></figcaption>
  </figure>`;
});


document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;



</script>
```

Comment: Give function implementation inside <script> tags. eg: `<script type="text/javascript">function function1(){ /* your code here */}</script>`

Answer (score 0):

The code below includes the function to sort the entries by likes in ascending order.

```js
const imgArr = [{
    src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0",
    Recent: "24/1/2018",
    Likes: 6
  },
  {
    src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0",
    Recent: "24/3/2018",
    Likes: 2
  },
  {
    src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0",
    Recent: "25/1/2018",
    Likes: 3
  },
  {
    src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0",
    Recent: "24/2/2018",
    Likes: 1
  },
];

/* Gemeric function to display array content on screen */
const init = (ar) => ar.map(el => {
  return `<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src=${
    el.src
  } style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
      <figcaption>Recent: ${el.Recent}<br>
        <span>Likes: ${el.Likes}</span></figcaption>
  </figure>`;
});

const sortByLikes = (a, b) => {
  if (a.Likes === b.Likes) {
    return 0;
  }
  return a.Likes > b.Likes ? 1 : -1;
};

/* Generate array sorted by number of likes ascending */
const function1 = () => {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = init([...imgArr].sort(sortByLikes));
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = init(imgArr);
```

```html
<button onclick="function1()">Sort Most Like</button>
<button onclick="function2">Sort Most Recent</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks it works like a charm. how do i store inside an object instead of hardcode?. i am using pug format btw.